# locking in Parallel Linq when updating UI elements

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, parallel-processing, locking

I'm using parallel linq to load a list of links from a text file. I'm checking each line whether it is a valid link(Uri) or not...if it is a valid Uri it is added to a Listbox. I'm just wondering if i should lock the ListBox.Items while adding a link to it.

Here is my code.

```
if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.ReadLines(openFile.FileName).AsParallel().AsOrdered().ForAll(x =>
        {
            if (x.IsValidUri())
            {
                //lock(siteList.Items)  <-should I?
                siteList.Invoke(new Action<string>(s => siteList.Items.Add(s)), x);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Side note: for the sample to make sense consider renaming "IsValidUri" to "SomeVerySlowCheck"... because otherwise `AsParallel` look completely useless.

Comment: IsValidUri is nothing more than a simple wrapper around Uri.TryCreate() call

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed. The sample code works well as an exercise, but if this is the real code, AsParallel introduces way too much overhead for the lightweight IsValidUri to be of much use.

Comment: @NathanA so it's probably a bad idea to use AsParallel until or unless IsValidUri requires a lot of processing or takes a lot of time...?

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem Exactly. Unless you have a REALLY large file, the time it takes for IsValidUri to process your file on the GUI thread would be faster than the user could perceive.  And if it did take a second or more, I'd just run the entire job on a single worker thread and then `Invoke` the change to the `Items` collection once when it was done.

Comment: One more note: `lock`'ing on public property considered bad practice, so if you write such code where `lock` is needed make sure to have your own private object to lock on (in cases of just protecting branches of `AsParallel` using local variable may be enough, but if accessing some shared property make sure to lock on object of similar scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to lock in this case.  Using `Invoke()` already forces all changes to the Items collection to occur synchronously on the GUI thread.

Because of that though, you're not really gaining anything by using `AsParallel()`.  You may want to consider using `BeginInvoke()` instead, which may speed things up a bit.  That way, the calling thread isn't waiting for the invoke to complete.

Comment: Am I missing something or is the Invoke useless in that case ? It would be better to lock the List instead of invoking everything on the same thread, no ?

Comment: Locking the list is useless, since you can only modify it on the GUI thread. Without invoke, you'll get an exception since you're modifying a control property outside of the GUI thread, but it nullifies the need for Parallel.  The best solution is to use `AsParallel()` with `BeginInvoke()`, which will allow multiple threads to "queue" updates to your list.

Comment: I thought only UI controls needed to be modified from the UI thread, not generic objects like a List ?

Comment: `siteList.Items` isn't a generic list.  It's a special type of list that is bound to the host control, and modifying it outside the GUI thread will cause exceptions.

Comment: I just realized the `Items` list wasn't just a property of the form, rather the list of Items in the control... This makes much more sense :)